# Monte Carlo with non uniform weighting

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, monte-carlo, law-of-large-numbers

So, I just want to check if what is in my mind is in fact true. Assume, that we have are given a distribution $p_{z}(k)$ over the whole $\mathbb{Z}^+$. We are interested in approximating $p_v(v)$ over some observed variable $v$. However, we are not given $p_v$ directly, but rather a joint $p(v,h) = p(h)p(v|h)$ such that the marginal $p_v(v)$ is intractable. Thus we seek to approximate $p_v(v)$ via importance sampling - e.g. taking sample from some $q(h)$ and using the fact that $$p_v(v) = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{p(v,h)}{q(h)}\right]_q$$
Thus usually what is done is to use MC to approximate p(v) via:
$$p_v(v) \approx \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{K} \frac{p(v,h_k)}{q(h_k)}$$
According to the strong law of large numbers, the approximation will be exact when $K \to \infty$, under some mild conditions, which we assume are true. However, I can re write this as:
$$ p_v(v) \approx \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{p_z(k)}{\sum_{i=1}^K p_z(i)}  \frac{p(v,h_k)}{q(h_k)}$$
Where in the MC case $p_z(k)$ is a degenerate uniform distribution, however the limit still exists and converges, assuming we define appropriately $\frac{p_z(k)}{\sum_{i=1}^K p_z(i)}$.
Now in the limit of infinite examples essentially we have:
$$ \lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{p_z(k)}{\sum_{i=1}^K p_z(i)}  \frac{p(v,h_k)}{q(h_k)} = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{p(v,h)}{q(h)}\right]_{p_z* q} = p_v(v)$$

Thus I have two questions. First, is my reasoning correct or is there some major flaw? Secondly, if there is no mistake, is it possible to pick better weights for the MC sampling (I think not) and why?

Comment: Your notation is confusing and honestly seems misleading even. Being perhaps a bit unnecessarily rigorous, the mean of the random variable $X$ is $\int_\Omega X(\omega) dP(\omega)$. If $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$ then it has a Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dP}{dQ}$, and you have $\int_\Omega X(\omega) \frac{dP}{dQ}(\omega) dQ(\omega)$.

Comment: Getting back to your context, assuming that $P,Q$ are concentrated on $\mathbb{Z}^+$, then the mean of $P$ is (by the above formula) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \frac{p(n)}{q(n)} q(n)$, or the average of $\frac{n p(n)}{q(n)}$ over $q(n)$. This does not seem to me to be the same as the formula at the top of your question. Indeed I do not even really understand the formula at the top of your question, since $\frac{p}{q}$ is not a random variable.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct my notation is really bad. So the distribution over the $\gamma$ is not the same p as what we want from the MC. Let me correct this. P and Q are assumed to be have the same support, but in general can be over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, now I think your setting is a bit different from the setting in my answer, since $p$ is not given directly. Feel free to comment on the places where they don't correspond and I can revise accordingly.

Comment: Let me finish editing the question, as you were right that it was phrased quite badly, so probably confusing.

Comment: Does it make more sense now?

Comment: It seems to be basically a diagonalization idea: scale up the number of samples and the cutoff range at the same time, so as to achieve approximation using uniform distributions on bounded sets. If I'm understanding correctly, then I think this will work in many *applied* situations but that it could break down for distributions with sufficiently fat tails. It might also behave weirdly for cases where the true distribution is actually bounded, not that you would want to use this in that case anyway. I'm not sure how to precisely formulate hypotheses for when it would work.

Comment: At any rate, I think it would be slow, because for large $K$ you will tend to give too much weight to large values of $k$.

Comment: So this is a standard procedure when using Monte Carlo sampling in Variational Inference. This idea of taking the samples with not the same weight in the Monte Carlo sum came to my mind. Intuitively it seems flawed, as to why you would put a different weight on different samples, but I could not show why it is flawed

Comment: Note that you can define $p_z(k)$ with a functional form, such that it decreases as $k$ increases.

Comment: That could still have the same problem; it's just not so clear to me that the appropriate scaling for the number of samples and the appropriate scaling for the range from which the samples should be taken are the same scaling. Though on reflection, it looks like this is OK if the variance is finite, or even if just a $1+\delta$th moment exists.

Comment: Note that $p_z$ gives you weightiing on each seperate sample, based on the total number of samples, which is predefined beforehead. The denominator is just to make sure that adds up to 1 for finite K

Comment: I don't think I understand that comment. You increase the available values of $k$ and at the same time increase the number of samples. These are the same number $K$. It is not clear that these should both be $K$; why shouldn't they be some $M(K)$ and $N(K)$ with $M \neq N$?

Comment: Aah, ok so they should be exactly the same. if you see the definitions of the 2nd and 3rd equations, the index k over $h_k$ is the same as the k in $p_z(k)$. The idea is this: You take some $K$ samples but you need to weight them by some predefined $p_z(k)$. Is there better option than $1/K$ . I think not, but why?

Comment: With no prior knowledge, there are no good options at all; in Bayesian language, there is no such thing as an "uninformed prior". There is such a thing as a "naive prior" but it still must assume *something*. (But perhaps I am misunderstanding the role of $p_z$?)